# how to login by resellerclub Email and password by custom url or API?

Tags: php, api

I am using the resellarclub api.  When there is a new customer in my website, I store his credential to my database also and give a hot to resellarclub also.

Now I want to login in to my website with my database id and password, and redirect to resellarclub account section with proper login session.

http://manage.belizenic.bz/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq981.html

I have set the Custom URL as per guide but I am unable to create the session and redirect with proper session.

Comment: you're welcome. Unfortunately I have no clue what exactly you mean by "give a ho to resellarclub". I guess you mean link, but I am not sure, so I left it as is for now ;)